# Bootstrap 3 Off-Canvas Sidebar Menu Like Facebook's

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, menu, twitter-bootstrap-3, sidebar

I'm using some examples of Bootstrap 3 for an off-canvas sidebar menu when it gets to mobile which can be seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/AllenDB/9aAjJ/

How would I go about getting the off-canvas menu adjusted to act like Facebook's search/friends online off-canvas menu to where it always starts at the top of the menu and you can only scroll within? As with my example the navbar is fixed so one may toggle the sidebar menu. But when you have scrolled down the actual page and toggle the menu you have to scroll back up to see the links. I would like to see how can I get this adjusted to where the menu starts at the top and pushes the content and fixed navbar to the side while being able to scroll within the menu and not the content?

The CSS:

```
    html,
    body { overflow-x: hidden; }
    body { padding-top: 70px;}
    .navbar { color: #FFF; }
    footer { padding: 30px 0; }


    /*
    * Off Canvas
    * --------------------------------------------------
    */
    @media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
       .row-offcanvas { position: relative; -webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease-out; -moz-transition: all 0.25s ease-out; transition: all 0.25s ease-out;  }

       .row-offcanvas-right
       .sidebar-offcanvas { right: -50%; /* 6 columns */ }

       .row-offcanvas-left
       .sidebar-offcanvas { left: -50%; /* 6 columns */ }

       .row-offcanvas-right.active { right: 50%; /* 6 columns */ }

       .row-offcanvas-left.active { left: 50%; /* 6 columns */ }

       .sidebar-offcanvas { position: absolute; top: 0; width: 50%; /* 6 columns */ }
    }
```

The HTML:

```
        <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
            <p class="pull-left visible-xs">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" data-toggle="offcanvas">Toggle nav</button>
            </p>

            <div class="col-xs-2 col-lg-3">
                <p>LOGO</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-lg-5">
                <p>SEARCH BAR</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-4 col-lg-4">
                <p>TWO LINKS</p>
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="row row-offcanvas row-offcanvas-left">
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 sidebar-offcanvas" id="sidebar" role="navigation">
                <div class="list-group">
                    <a href="#" class="list-group-item active">Link</a>
                    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Link</a>
                    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Link</a>
                    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Link</a>
                    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Link</a>
                    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Link</a>
                    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Link</a>
                    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Link</a>
                    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Link</a>
                    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Link</a>
                </div>
            </div><!--/span-->

            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9">
                <div class="jumbotron">
                    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
                    <p>This is an example to show the potential of an offcanvas layout pattern in Bootstrap. Try some responsive-range viewport sizes to see it in action.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-4">
                        <h2>Heading</h2>
                        <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
                        <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
                    </div><!--/span-->
                    <div class="col-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-4">
                        <h2>Heading</h2>
                        <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
                        <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
                    </div><!--/span-->
                    <div class="col-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-4">
                        <h2>Heading</h2>
                        <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
                        <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
                    </div><!--/span-->
                    <div class="col-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-4">
                        <h2>Heading</h2>
                        <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
                        <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
                    </div><!--/span-->
                    <div class="col-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-4">
                        <h2>Heading</h2>
                        <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
                        <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
                    </div><!--/span-->
                    <div class="col-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-4">
                        <h2>Heading</h2>
                        <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
                        <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
                    </div><!--/span-->
                    <div class="col-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-4">
                        <h2>Heading</h2>
                        <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
                        <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
                    </div><!--/span-->
                    <div class="col-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-4">
                        <h2>Heading</h2>
                        <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
                        <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
                    </div><!--/span-->
                    <div class="col-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-4">
                        <h2>Heading</h2>
                        <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
                        <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
                    </div><!--/span-->
                    <div class="col-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-4">
                        <h2>Heading</h2>
                        <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
                        <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
                    </div><!--/span-->
                </div><!--/row-->
            </div>
        </div><!--/row /row-offcanvas-left-->

        <hr>

        <footer>
        <p>&copy; Company 2013</p>
        </footer>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understand the question, I think you're looking to have the sidebar scroll independently of the main content.

See if this Bootply example works..

http://bootply.com/101543

Facebook style template: 
http://www.bootstrapzero.com/bootstrap-template/facebook

Comment: Thanks for the example! I think this maybe something I'm looking for. I'll have to play around with it to see for sure.

Comment: I think I got some partial things together. For the most part the offcanvas menu scrolls when in mobile, but to an extent, and then you begin to scroll through the whole content even if the offcanvas menu is still active. Also, I tried applying a fixed position for the searchbar that appears in the offcanvas menu, but that just makes it fixed on mobile and desktop.

View here: http://playground.diademagency.com/bootstrap/

Comment: Since you are using a wrapper to fix the page size to the screen size, a problem pops up. window.scrollTo no longer removes the browser chrome when using this pattern on a mobile device, since there is nothing to scroll. Any suggestions on how to deal with that?