# Convert Dropdown Accordion to Slideout Menu by adding toggle_class()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a menu built using Bootstrap 3.0. It floats to the left and can be re-sized to fit only the icons by adding a css class to it using jQuery's toggle_class(). What I want to achieve is once this menu is toggled to a smaller version, I would like the drop down menu to become a vertical slide out menu. 
Here is an example of what I am trying to accomplish http://wrapbootstrap.com/preview/WB0B30DGR If there is a plugin that does please point me to it.

Here is my HTML code:

```
    <div id="wrap">
    <div id="content">      
        <div id="navigation" class="" role="navigation">

            <!-- Sidebar -->
            <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
                <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
                <div class="navbar-header">
                  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="fa fa-bar"></span>
                    <span class="fa fa-bar"></span>
                    <span class="fa fa-bar"></span>
                  </button>
                  <a class="navbar-brand" href="./">CIMP Admin</a>
                </div>

                <!--SIDENAV
                ============================================= -->
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav side-nav">
                        <li class="active" ><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> Dashboard</a></li>
                        <li class="dropdown ">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="fa fa-camera"></i> Media <b class="caret"></b></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-picture-o"></i> Library</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-picture-o"></i> Albums</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-picture-o"></i> Slideshows</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <!-- Modules -->
                        <li class="dropdown ">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="fa fa-puzzle-piece"></i> Modules <b class="caret"></b></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-thumb-tack"></i> Posts</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-cloud"></i> Uploads</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-desktop"></i> Testimonials</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>           
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-users"></i> Users</a></li>
                        <li calss="active"><a id="toggle-pane" href="#"><i class="fa fa-caret-square-o-left"></i> Hide Menu Bar</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav><!--/ nav -->

        </div><!--/ navigation -->
    </div><!--/ content -->
</div><!-- wrap -->

<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#toggle-pane").click(function () {
        $('#wrap').toggleClass("folded");
    });
</script>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20685538/1004312

Comment: Thank you for the help. However, I can do what the reply posted above is showing. What I would like to be able to do is move my mouse over the minified menu item and see top level items (icon and text together) and the sub level items.

Comment: Please the example in the image here: [link](http://cimwebdesigns.com/_content/default/Temp Photo.JPG)

Comment: http://www.berriart.com/sidr/#usage